# Webpack 4: Load splitChunks module through JS during runtime

Tags: webpack, import, webpack-4

My webpack build outputs 3 bundles.

1. The entry point.
2. node_modules code, generated by `splitChunks`
3. The extracted css file.

This is a library meant to be used by other devs, so I don't control the HTML that the entry point is loaded from. A user is going to include the entry point with `<script>`, then my application code should somehow load bundles 2 && 3, which have hashed names.

To be clear, I don't want to load modules with dynamic imports, (i.e. modules you npm install, or files you import), I want to load the webpack output chunk that contains modules.

(I actually have 2 entrypoints, which is why bundle #2 exists, but I left it out for simplicity.)

Comment: share your webpack config please

Answer (score 3):

**Webpack v4** has latest upgrades. Previously if  we do code splitting, You can see in **devTools** of browser, the `initiator` of main.bundle.js in `*(index)*` which means `index.html` requested the `main.bundle.js`. Afterwards all scripts are loaded from **bootstrap_a877….** (a script) This is the Webpack script that is responsible for asynchronously loading files. This script is added to the build automatically when you use Webpack’s dynamic import function.

But in webpack v4 we have **runtimeChunk** which is actually becomes the initiator of all bundles. You can see it in your dev tools. You  need to enable runtimeChunk

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: 'single',
}
```

I hope this would be helpful.

[My answer on a different post regarding code splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120638/how-webpack-4-code-splitting-work-is-there-a-hidden-code-which-makes-a-http-req/52121145#52121145)

Comment: Okay so this produces another js file called runtime.js. When I load it into the html, it doesn't actually perform http requests to load the other chunks?

Comment: It does. It just tells the browser which bundles need to be downloaded

Comment: @SakhiMansoor is there a way to know if all chunks are loaded? I have a case where I search for the module when loaded completely after I load runtime.js

`var module=window[moduleName]`

when using splitchunk with runtime 'single' its undefined but when I load all modules manually it loads properly.